# Do I incur charges when downloading on an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I use AWS free tier to spin up t2.micro boxes and use it to practice Docker since the download speed is vastly great when pulling large images in mere seconds.

I am assuming download is free and upload -pushing images for example- is chargeable although not sure the exact amount.

How much are the costs here?

Comment: It used to be 15 GB of bandwitch in total for everything. But now I can't find official info on this. So don't know if it still applies or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You incur upload costs when you exceed more than 1 GB upload per month. Please see: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/#Data_Transfer

Note that I'm providing a link here rather than providing values because the costs may differ from Region to Region, and from year to year.

For more information on the Free tier limits have a play with: https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Also, remember that it is 750 hours of t2.micro or t3.micro a month. You could spend all these 750 hours with 1 instance and that would take 750 hours. If however you decided to run 750 instances then you would use up your whole months 750 hours in 1 hour.

Lastly remember your EBS limit is 30 GiB. If you launched 4 Ubuntu instances with 4 root volumes of 8 GiB then you would be exceeding your free tier limit by 2 GiB.

Comment: Free tier upload is now 100 GB/mo (same link)

Answer (score 2):

**Data Transfer IN To Amazon EC2 From Internet:** No charge

**Data Transfer OUT From Amazon EC2 To Internet** is charged at 9c/GB (in US regions).

Also: *"As part of AWS’s Free Usage tier, new AWS customers will receive free 15 GB of data transfer out each month aggregated across all AWS services for one year except in the AWS GovCloud region."*